# AngularJS Http Interceptor Doesn't Work

Tags: angularjs

Trying to make the commented code in script.js work:
http://plnkr.co/edit/VQCZtqzshMXJA8YTSxdr?p=preview

Can anyone help?

```
myApp.config([
'$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {



    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function () {
        return {
            'request': function () {
                // same as above
                alert('request');
            },

            'response': function () {
                // same as above
                alert('response');
            }
        };
    });

}
```

]);

Answer (score 0):

Draw your attention at interceptors documentation

[Interceptors](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors)

> request: interceptors get called with a http config object. The  function is free to modify the config object or create a new one. **The function needs to return the config object directly, or a promise containing the config or a new config object.**
>
> requestError: interceptor gets called when a previous interceptor threw an error or resolved with a rejection.
>
> response: interceptors get called with http response object. The function is free to modify the response object or create a new one. **The function needs to return the response object directly, or as a promise containing the response or a new response object.**
>
> responseError: interceptor gets called when a previous interceptor threw an error or resolved with a rejection.

```
myApp.config([
  '$httpProvider',
  function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function() {
      return {
        'request': function(config) {
          // same as above
          alert('request');
          return config;
        },
        'response': function(data) {
          // same as above
          alert('response');
          return data;
        }
      };
    });

  }
]);
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/EjoAVj6B6xmbgyT4ctg9?p=preview)